# Android device on mac cannot establish session because of Error: socket hang up

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Can't start an Appium session with Android physical devices, although emulators seems to work fine on my imac (Sierra).

Any thoughts?

> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: ProxyRequestError: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up
>       at JWProxy.proxy$ (../../../lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:152:13)
>       at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
>       at

Comment: hi, did you manage to find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: I think changing the Automator capability to Appium not uiautomaor works